# Missing Provisioning Profile error when archiving using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

to automate my app build process, I am trying to build my iOS app via command line

Build command

```
xcodebuild archive -project sample.xcodeproj -scheme "sample" -archivePath $PWD/archive/sample.xcarchive -destination generic/platform=iOS -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

Export Command

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/archive/sample.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ./ExportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

Following is the error

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""sample.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="sample.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

Please note that the archive from Xcode works fine. 
And the Info.plist file from archive folder `archive/sample.xcarchive/Info.plist` does not contain provisioning profiles dictionary.

As per other suggestions on google and StackOverflow, I have tried the following

1. Changed build settings to Legacy build
2. Removed Provisioning profiles folder from ~/Library/MobileDevice
3. Upgraded Xcode to latest (currently 11.4)
4. created a softling of ~/Library/MobileDevice in /Library/MobileDevice
5. Recreated provisioning profile in developer account.

Could anyone help me get over this issue?

Comment: You have to create a export option plist. in that you have to specify the build rules and provision profiles.

Comment: If you look into my export command, that is exactly what i did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What has finally worked is to remove wildcard while mentioning the App id in the exportOptions.plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dict>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APP_ID_WITHOUT_WILDCARD_CHAR</key>
        <string>PROVISIOING_PROFILE_NAME_AS_SEEN_BY_XCODE</string>
    </dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iPhone Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after upgrading to XCode 11.3. It's related to new [Apple Development and Apple Distribution certificate types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes).

Edit provisioning profile and select use in Xcode 11.
Use this new provisioning profile to fix this error.

Comment: Yup! I did that already. I have recreated a provisioning profile and a certificate in the developer site. Is there anything else you did?

Comment: Removed all provisioning profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and downloaded it again from Xcode preferences -> Accounts -> Download Manual Profile.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Tried redoing all of the steps.. still the same error...